# Authorization Header is missing if request sent via Zuul API Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, angular5, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

When i send Authorization Header from rest client(postman), also from browser, to back end `springboot(2.0.3v)` AuthorizationService `(without API Gateway)`, the `'Authorization'` Header will be exists and every flow works fine.

But when i send the same Header through API Gateway, The 'Authorization' Header will be missed. This header will be present in all filters of API Gate way. But it will be missed in `backend(AuthorizationService)'s filter`.

Kindly help what might be cause? **any filter is intercepting to avoid Authorization Header?** I have also registered CORS Filter with Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" and Access-Control-Allow-Headers to "*".

Answer (score 0):

API gateway has a lambda proxy integrated when you are integrating lambda function with it, if ur wrapping a http url to it, you need to pass the header in Method integration section and also enable CORS by clicking on resource and manually adding the headers with custom name and enabling cors might help.